# Possible to programmatically tap textfields and paste username/passwords? Login not saved in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, http, iphone-6

I am trying to help my boss and co-workers out with an iOS 12 Swift App to help us all better manage inventory when out on the shop floor.

The all works by taking advantage of the barcode/QR-code reading technology that comes bundled with iOS 12.

The webpage used to log into the inventory service uses plain-old http technology and so the iOS (appears) not to be offering me a means of letting me save/retrieve the password to/from the Keychain. I CAN however save the login information when I access the website via my Mac. I have verified that the login information been saved on the Mac's keychain (which is shared with the iPhone via iCloud).

The webpage warns that the password (on either platform) will be sent unencrypted.

I have adapted some of the code already at https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/.

I don't have a full Apple developer account, so at present this is not a production app.

The main difference between the code supplied by www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift and mine nearly all lies in the 'QRSwiftController.swift' file's func launchApp function. Slight modifications to help improve readability and usability. A Safari View Controller is used make everything more cohesive inside of one app etc.

```
 func launchApp(decoded_barcode: String) {

    if presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }

    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

    let result = decoded_barcode.replacingOccurrences( of:"[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)


    let startOfURL: String = "http://xxx.webname.com/deploy/artikel.php?nummer="
    let fullURL = startOfURL + result


    let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Open App", message: "You're going to open \(fullURL)", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        if let url = URL(string: fullURL){
            let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertPrompt.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Even when I visit the inventory management website via normal Safari on my iPhone I am prompted for a username/password every time.

[image: Login]

Alt URL for login screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2XFO.jpg

Is there any way I possibly circumvent this problem by automating the tapping of the text fields for the username/password (following by pasting the info) and then tapping 'Log in'??

I've looked already for solutions on Stackoverflow but they seem overwhelmingly complicated and/or no longer valid for Swift 4.

Thanks!

Assume generic username and passwords such as 'user' and 'password'.

Comment: Short answer is yes. All that user inputs do is trigger methods and so if you want to mimic a user gesture, just call the method that is bound to that gesture. As for pasting, `UITextField` has a `text` property that you can change which is all that a paste does. `UITextField` also has a delegate which can help you react to events that mimic user gestures. And then simply call the login method that is bound to the tap of the login button.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly! The username and password fields that appear on login screen are not something that I coded myself though?

Comment: I’d revise your question to isolate the real problem which is how to retrieve the authentication credentials from the webpage. The programmatic mimicking of user gestures is all secondary and really separate from authentication. Right?

Comment: You are very probably correct. I have hunch though that by virtue of the fact that the technology used by the login page is only old-school http and nothing more modern (as well as warning about passwords being send unencrypted) a more straight forward means of retrieving/submitting login information is not possible on iOS. When I substitute in something like 'HTTPS ://www.facebook.com' I don't have this problem at all.

Comment: Anything is possible in OOP. The fact that the auth credentials are unencrypted should help you here. You just need to build a mechanism that captures them when they’re entered and store them somewhere with persistence.

Comment: I tried changing the URL to have https... instead of http.... It lets me know that the login info will be send securely but still no dice in terms of having the username/password recalled automatically for future visits. A bummer. :(

Comment: Cool bsod. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

In the end (as a workaround) I just got Google Chrome (on iOS) to do all the donkey-work (it appears willing to save the password for this website for future retrieval).

```
if URL(string: fullURL) != nil {
    //let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    //self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: fullURL)! as URL) 
}
```